# How can I do d3.svg.arc within a given map projection?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Having troubles finding information to draw a circular sector on a given map projection in D3.js.  I have been using [d3.svg.arc](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-arc), but now I need to transform it to given d3.geo projections.

Note, this is not for drawing arcs between two points, but circular sectors (think pie wedges).

Comment: Have you tried projecting the coordinates of the arc?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that calculates the coordinates along the desired arc in spherical coordinates (making use of the `d3.geo.rotation` function to save yourself the headache of figuring out the correct equations) and returns a `LineString` object:

```
function geoArc(center, radius, startAngle, endAngle, steps) {
    coordinates = []
    for (var i = 0; i <= steps; i++) {
        var curAngle = (startAngle + (endAngle - startAngle) * i / steps);
        coordinates[i] = d3.geo.rotation(center)(d3.geo.rotation([0, 0, curAngle])([radius, 0]))
    }
    return {
        type: "LineString",
        coordinates: coordinates
    };
}
```

This can then be used to create the desired arc like this:

```
svg.append("path")
    .datum(geoArc([20, 40], 30, -20, 230, 40))
    .classed("circle", true)
    .attr("d", path);
```

This generates an arc centered at 20°E, 40°N with a radius of 30°, running from -20° to 230°:

[image]

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eN4uv/)