# D3 arcs on (inverted) stereographic projection not displaying as required

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Following on from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766430/how-can-i-do-d3-svg-arc-within-a-given-map-projection, I have a slightly modified version where I want to display an arc at a certain Azimuth, Zenith Angle and a given opening angle. My efforts so far are below.

If I create an arc at (Az,Ze) 0,90 and 0,45 the arcs are where I expect them. However, if I want an arc at every Az = 45 degrees for Ze = 45 degrees, the arc tends to go off the projection instead of going around.

Any idea what is happening here? Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3p9c4kzo/1/

```
var width = 600,
height = 600;

var flippedStereographic = function(lam, phi)  {
            var cosl = Math.cos(lam),
            cosp = Math.cos(phi),
            k = 1 / (1 + cosl * cosp);
            return [ k * cosp * Math.sin(lam), -k * Math.sin(phi) ];
};

var projection = d3.geo
.projection(flippedStereographic)
.rotate([0, -90])
.scale(180)
.translate([width / 2, height / 2])
.clipAngle(90)
.precision(.1);

var path = d3.geo.path()
.projection(projection);

var graticule = d3.geo.graticule();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

svg.append("defs").append("path")
.datum({
type: "Sphere"
})
.attr("id", "sphere")
.attr("d", path);

svg.append("use")
.attr("class", "stroke")
.attr("xlink:href", "#sphere");

svg.append("use")
.attr("class", "fill")
.attr("xlink:href", "#sphere");

svg.append("path")
.datum(graticule)
.attr("class", "graticule")
.attr("d", path);

function geoArc(center, radius, startAngle, endAngle, steps) {
coordinates = []
for (var i = 0; i <= steps; i++) {
    var curAngle = (startAngle + (endAngle - startAngle) * i / steps);
    coordinates[i] = d3.geo.rotation(center)(d3.geo.rotation([0, 0, 
curAngle])([radius, 0]))
}
return {
    type: "LineString",
    coordinates: coordinates
};
}

svg.append("path")
.datum(geoArc([0,90], 30, 0, 360, 40))
.classed("circle", true)
.attr("d", path);

svg.append("path")
    .datum(geoArc([0,45], 30, 0, 360, 40))
.classed("circle", true)
.attr("d", path);

svg.append("path")
    .datum(geoArc([45,45], 30, 0, 360, 40))
.classed("circle", true)
.attr("d", path);

svg.append("path")
    .datum(geoArc([90,45], 30, 0, 360, 40))
.classed("circle", true)
.attr("d", path);
```

Comment: Interestingly, if I change the projection to just orthographic, I see the correct representation of the circle->ellipse, even though the Azimuth=0 is no longer pointing true north. I guess the algorithm presented above is orthographic-specific.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the code is appropriate for both Orthographic and Stereographic projections. Orthographic distorts and is not conformal, whereas Stereographic is conformal and does not distort (well, not as much).

Orthographic
https://au.mathworks.com/help/map/ortho.html

Stereographic
https://au.mathworks.com/help/map/stereo.html

Comment: Did you mean to edit your question, or add an answer that explains that you didn't have an actual problem, or what?

Comment: The second option :) I thought an answer would close it.